# Type 'StatefulElement' is not a subtype of type 'Context' - Exception caught by widgets library

Tags: flutter, dart

The Flutter application produced the following error:

> type 'StatefulElement' is not a subtype of type 'Context'

I am using the following packages: [PDF](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) and [Printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing).

I am informed that the possible cause of the error is the call to the `_visualizarPdf (context, path)`  function

The *_visualizarPdf* function displays the PDF using the [flutter_full_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer) package and this is working. The error occurs when I click the print icon.

The function responsible for generating the impression, according to the package [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing), is the Printing.layoutPdf, of the Printer package.

Before I was trying to pass the _visualizarPdf in a StatelessWidget, outside the _visualizarPdf function, however another error occurred, when it passed in this way, the attributes were returning null, not generating the PDF

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

Future<Uint8List> segundaViaReport(context, Orgao orgao) async {
    final pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
    final String nomeMunicipio = orgao.descricao;

    pw.Widget _header(pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Column(
            children: <pw.Widget>[
                pw.Text(nomeMunicipio, textScaleFactor: 2),            
                pw.Divider(height: 2.0),
            ],
        );
    }

    Widget _visualizarPdf(pw.Context context, pathDirectory) {
        final String path = pathDirectory;
    
        return PDFViewerScaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(""),
            actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.print), onPressed: () {
                Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (format) => segundaViaReport(context, orgao));
            }),
            ],
        ),
        path: path,
        );
    }

    pdf.addPage(
        pw.MultiPage(
        orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
        margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
        header: _header,
        build: (pw.Context context) => [
            pw.Wrap(children: <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <pw.Widget>[              
                _IdentificarObservacoes(orgao),
                ],
            ),
            ]),
        ],
        ),
    );

    final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    final String path = '$dir/segunda_via.pdf';
    final File file = File(path);
    await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => _visualizarPdf(context, path),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Which line specifically is throwing the error?

Comment: Would help if you post how you use the function you're showing in your comment ;) obviously at some point in your code, you pass a context to a widget, which is in fact a stateful widget. Seems like a easy problem to soleve. But I don't see right now where do you use your function.